# save synchronous (not duplicate) information in a asynchronous process

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, stack, mean

For this MEAN Stack project, I would like to save in the same collection documents with:

- different types
- unique chronological number per type.

example:

{ID: 1, type: 'a', chrono: 1}

{ID: 2, type: 'b', chrono: 1}

{ID: 3, type: 'b', chrono: 2}

{ID: 4, type: 'a', chrono: 2}

{ID: 5, type: 'b', chrono: 3}

...

On the front end, I use a loop

```
for ( var i++; i < type.length; i++) // lets say Document type = ["a", "b"]

      for (var j++; j< 100; j++) // Creates 100 documents

        // Front end service request directing to the NodeJS Server to create a document
serverDocument.createDocument(dataS).success(function(dataR){
                        counterDOC ++;
$scope.documentID= dataR._id;
}
```

The nodeJS Server is looking for the last Chrono Number in DB for the selected type of document and add 1.

```
doc = new db.Document (req.body); // req.body is for example {type: 'a'}
doc.save();

getChrono (doc); // home made function
```

The get Chrono function:

```
var getChrono = function(doc){ 

    var config=
        {

            type : doc.type,

        }

  query = db.Document.findOne(config).sort({$natural:-1}); 

  query.exec(function (err, chrn){

        doc.chrono = 1;

      if (chrn != null)

          if(chrn.chrono != null)

            doc.chrono= chrn.chrono+1;

      doc.update();

  });
```

And the result is something similar to that:

{ID: 1, type: 'a', chrono: 1}

{ID: 2, type: 'a', chrono: 1}

{ID: 3, type: 'a', chrono: 1}

{ID: 4, type: 'a', chrono: 1}

{ID: 5, type: 'a', chrono: 2}
...
Of course the Object ID is unique but the chronological numbers are not unique for a type of document.

I understand that the information are not yet saved in DB when the next request is launched. Therefore the 'last chrono number' in DB is not the last chrono number in reality.

Can somebody has **a method to solve this problem**?
I **do not want a synchronous solution** on the front end side and it would be logical to have the server side to manage the chrono Number

Comment: You'll need a queue to process your items in a sync way.

Comment: Hi Dieterg, I don't want to do it on the front end side cos the problem of getting 2 users making the same operation could lead to a bug.. AND i have no idea how to make it on the serverside.. maybe i miss a function?

Comment: You can also add this functionality on the server. :-

Comment: OK I'll have a look at it then. thanks

Comment: Take a look at [servicebus](https://github.com/mateodelnorte/servicebus). Might be overkill for your solution though, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Is there no way to  access to a "memory" when the object is create with "new Document" ?? Sorry for stupid question

Answer (score 0):

You can `save` doc after incrementing `chrono`

So below `saveDoc` will work.

```
function saveDoc(docBody,callback){
    var query = db.Document.findOne({type:docBody.type}).sort({chrono:-1});// I guess $natural is not that reliable
    query.exec(function (err, chrn){
      if(err)
        return callback(err);
      docBody.chrono = chrn && chrn.chrono != null?chrn.chrono+1:1;

      var doc = new db.Document(docBody); // Doc created here after getting chrono
      doc.save(callback);
  });
}
```

Then call function with request body

```
saveDoc(req.body,function(){
 console.log('saved');
});
```

Comment: Hi JagsSparrow .. I implemented your function in the program but the result is the "same" The chono number is not taken into account as it should be

Comment: It looks like the computer take far too much time to save the information compare to read and it can read 3/4 inputs before it actually can save a new documents.